# How Dagster execute Window .Bat file?

Tags: dagster

I would like to know how Dagster enable the job to execute Window *.BAT file by login into other Window server and execute the *.bat file which located in that Window Server?

Anyone of you know about the answer, related solution or code sample about my question above?